# wpf: how to set placement of pop left-bottom

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set location on popup left of screen instead of right.
This code set position in right but I want to changed in left:

```
 <Popup x:Name="popup" IsOpen="True" Width="250" Height="90" Placement="AbsolutePoint" 
        AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade">
```

In the code behind:

```
popup.VerticalOffset = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight - 200;
popup.HorizontalOffset = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth - 300;
```

Comment: So change this? `popup.HorizontalOffset = 300;` If HorizontalOffset works to right so this should work to left.

Comment: Can't test right now so this might not work. But try `Placement="Absolute"` and `HorizontalOffset="0"`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750577(v=vs.85).aspx for placement details of popups

Comment: @grek40 it's Ok . but i set `100` instead of 0 for distance around.my question it's that in different monitor size ,is the problem caused ? or not??

Comment: I don't know what "problem" you are talking about. The screen coordinates are calculated starting at the upper left corner. So the lower left corner coordinate is at `(0, PrimaryScreenHeight - 1)` and the lower right corner is at `(PrimaryScreenWidth - 1, PrimaryScreenHeight - 1)` and the way you set your offsets, it is placing the popup relative to the lower right corner. There is only placement, no "problem".